# Want SQL statement to return all columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Write a `SELECT` statement that returns the LastName, FirstName, and AnnualSalary columns of each  instructor that has a unique annual salary. In other words, don’t include instructors that have the same annual salary as another instructor.

And the code that I tried is

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    LastName,
    FirstName,
    AnnualSalary
FROM
    Instructors i
WHERE
    i.AnnualSalary NOT IN (SELECT AnnualSalary
                           FROM Instructors i1
                           WHERE i.AnnualSalary <> i1.AnnualSalary)
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Your logic is incorrect, your subquery needs to find where annual salary is the *same* but the instructure is *different*

Comment: The question title also seems completely unrelated to the actual description

Comment: Learn to break your problem into pieces that you can accomplish and that can help you achieve your goal. In this case, how would you do that? You want to find all salary values that have no duplicates. Typically we count those values and use a HAVING clause as already demonstrated. Is that one of the topics you have recently studied? Those topics are clues about the solution to your homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close, try with this change

```
SELECT 
    LastName,
    FirstName,
    AnnualSalary
FROM
    Instructors i
WHERE
    i.AnnualSalary NOT IN (SELECT AnnualSalary
                           FROM Instructors i1
                           group by AnnualSalary
                           having count(*) > 1)
```

i removed the distinct keyword as it is not required

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT LastName, FirstName, AnnualSalary
FROM Instructors
WHERE AnnualSalary NOT IN
(SELECT AnnualSalary
FROM Instructors
GROUP BY AnnualSalary
HAVING COUNT(AnnualSalary) > 1)
ORDER BY LastName, FirstName;
```

Comment: Please provide more information to the OP. Posting answers without explanations is not accepted.

Comment: This *is* the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer,

```
SELECT i1.* 
FROM Instructors i1
WHERE (SELECT count(1) 
       FROM Instructors i2 
       WHERE i1.AnnualSalary = i2.AnnualSalary and not (i1.FirstName = i2.FirstName and i1.LastName = i2.LastName) 
      )<>1
```

Hope you will got your answer.